# Are the eigenvalues of a matrix sum the same as the sum of the eigenvalues of individual matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If I have A and B, both nxn, with eigenvalues a and b respectively, will a-b be an eigenvalue of the matrix A-B?

Comment: No, that's not possible, except in special cases. Just count the possibilities.

Comment: How would you choose to add which $\lambda_k$ with which $\mu_k$ ? By having them ordered in a previous step  ? But if they are complex, how would you do this ordering ?

Answer (score 2):

No unless they share eigenvectors. If $\vec v$ is an eigenvector of both $A$ and $B$, $$A\vec v=a\vec v\\B\vec v=b\vec v$$Then $$(A-B)\vec v=(a-b)\vec v$$so $a-b$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix. If they do not share the same eigenspaces, then you cannot guarantee that this will be an eigenvalue (it still can be, but you can't tell in general).